# Integrating hyperlinks into map labels in QGIS / QGIS2web

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I use QGIS2web for creating interactive maps for web deployment via GITHUB and GITLAB.

For a new project, I would like to integrate hyperlinks to an archival resource into the labels of my point data and make them "clickable".

Is there a way to manage this within the QGIS2web workflow?

If not, I could, of course, manipulate the final HTML files manually, but I have about 2000 points. So I might try and amend my HTML via script if there is no QGIS-native fix.

All links to tutorials etc. are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You could use URLs for the popups. Example with leaflet export: Create a new text field "URL" within the point layer table, for example "https://www.visitberlin.de". Result:
[image]
https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright

You can also use URLs within text, for example:
"Visit our website https://www.visitberlin.de"

Comment: Leaflet export in QGIS2web worked perfectly, indeed. I couldn't get it to work with Mapbox, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a screenshot how QGIS2web renders hyperlinks if a Leaflet export is selected and if the table column containing the links is chosen as an "in-line" label:

[image]

Comment: In addition you have the possibility to hide some data / to hide some fields within the popup: Layer Properties - Attributes Form - choose field/s, widget type: Hidden.